# Multithread and AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: pandas, multithreading, python-re

We wrote this code in order to plot the data conteined in a txt file:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import numpy as np
import os

names = ['CH','LG','HG','Ts(ns)','ToT(ns)']
righe_primo_header = 5
righe_header = 5
canali = 64

# input file
infile = 'Run1_list.txt' 

# determinare numero di righe, poi di eventi nel file di input
stream = os.popen('wc -l '+ infile)
nrighe = stream.read()
match = re.match(r" (\S+)\s*", nrighe, re.I)
items = match.groups()
nrighe = float(items[0])
#print( 'nrighe = ',nrighe)

# numero di blocchi di dati da leggere
ntrigger = (nrighe - righe_primo_header) / (canali + righe_header) - 1
ntrigger = int( ntrigger)
print('trovati ',ntrigger,' eventi')
ncanali_histo = int(np.sqrt(ntrigger))

ncanali_histo = 4096

events = []

file1 = open( infile, 'r')
for line in range(righe_primo_header-1):
    line = file1.readline()
    #print('saltiamo riga ', line)

line=file1.readline()
for trigger in range(ntrigger):
#while line:
    for lineh in range(righe_header):
        line = file1.readline()
        #print('saltiamo ',line)
    for canale in range(canali):
        line = file1.readline()
        #print(' elaboriamo ',line)
        match = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+", line, re.I)
        temparray = []
        if match:
            items = match.groups()
            #print(items)
            for colonna in range(len(items)):
                col = items[colonna]
                if col == '-':
                    valore = 0
                else:
                    valore = float(items[colonna])
                temparray.append( valore )
                #print('blocco ', trigger, ' colonna ', colonna, ' ', items[colonna],' -> ',valore)
            #print('temparray = ',temparray)

        events.append(temparray)
                
file1.close()

print('ultimo trigger ID letto: ', trigger)
#print('events = ',events)

df = pd.DataFrame( events, columns = names)
print(df)

# istogramma di HG per canale fissato
canale = 44
plot_df = df.loc[ df['CH'] == canale ]
print('plot_df per istogramma:')
print(plot_df)
plot_df.hist(column='HG', bins=ncanali_histo)
plt.title('Multiphoton spectrum HG channel ' + str(canale) )

# seleziona un evento
evento = 3
plot_df = df[ (canali * evento):(canali*evento + canali) ]
print('plot_df per scatter plot:')
print(plot_df)
plot_df.plot.scatter(x='CH', y='HG', c='red')
plt.title('HG vs CH event ' + str(evento) )




plt.show()
```

This code perfectly works in MacOs but not in Linux and Windows (of course becouse we dont use wc command, no problem) and we get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read_list.py", line 20, in <module>
    items = match.groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Why this errors happens?

Then, the txt file is of the order of GB, how can i run the code using the multithread? Can you help me?

I upload a small example of data here (see raw): https://pastebin.com/raw/PjVYc3vn

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the firt issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import re
import numpy as np
import os

names = ['CH','LG','HG','Ts(ns)','ToT(ns)']
righe_primo_header = 5
righe_header = 5
canali = 64

# input file
infile = 'Run1_list.txt' 

# determinare numero di righe, poi di eventi nel file di input
stream = os.popen('wc -l '+ infile)
nrighe = stream.read()
#print( 'nrighe = ',nrighe)
match = re.match(r"\s*(\S+) (.*)", nrighe, re.I)
#print( match)
items = match.groups()
nrighe = float(items[0])
#print( 'nrighe = ',nrighe)

# numero di blocchi di dati da leggere
ntrigger = (nrighe - righe_primo_header) / (canali + righe_header) - 1
ntrigger = int( ntrigger)
print('trovati ',ntrigger,' eventi')
ncanali_histo = int(np.sqrt(ntrigger))

ncanali_histo = 4096

events = []

file1 = open( infile, 'r')
for line in range(righe_primo_header-1):
    line = file1.readline()
    #print('saltiamo riga ', line)

line=file1.readline()
for trigger in range(ntrigger):
#while line:
    for lineh in range(righe_header):
        line = file1.readline()
        #print('saltiamo ',line)
    for canale in range(canali):
        line = file1.readline()
        #print(' elaboriamo ',line)
        match = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+", line, re.I)
        temparray = []
        if match:
            items = match.groups()
            #print(items)
            for colonna in range(len(items)):
                col = items[colonna]
                if col == '-':
                    valore = 0
                else:
                    valore = float(items[colonna])
                temparray.append( valore )
                #print('blocco ', trigger, ' colonna ', colonna, ' ', items[colonna],' -> ',valore)
            #print('temparray = ',temparray)

        events.append(temparray)
                
file1.close()

print('ultimo trigger ID letto: ', trigger)
#print('events = ',events)

df = pd.DataFrame( events, columns = names)
print('Il dataframe totale è il seguente: ', df)

# istogramma di HG per canale fissato
canale = 44

plot_df = df.loc[ (df['CH'] == canale) | (df['CH'] == 50)]

print('Il dataframe selezionato è il seguente: ', plot_df)

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==44] *= (1.096)

fig = px.histogram(plot_df, x='HG', color='CH', barmode='overlay', opacity=0.8, title='Multiphoton spectrum HG channel')
fig.update_traces(xbins=dict(start=0.0, end=4096.0, size=1))

fig.show()

# seleziona un evento
evento = 3

plot_df2 = df[(canali * evento):(canali*evento + canali)]

print('Il dataframe per lo scatter plot HG vs Ch relativo all evento ',evento, 'è il seguente: ', plot_df2)

fig2 = px.scatter(plot_df2, x='CH', y='HG', title='HG vs CH event ' + str(evento) )
fig2.show()
```

Now, how can i compile it in multithread?